# Как работает динамический import?

Tags: javascript, импорт

Со статическими импортами все более-менее понятно

```
import A from "a.js";
```

Сборщик натыкается на эту строку, зависимость резолвится и в конечном итоге попадает в готовый бандл.

С динамическими импортами уже возникают вопросы. Если значение подгружаемого модуля  динамическое (что, насколько я знаю, невозможно со статическими импортами), например

```
import(`/assets/${ asset }`);
```

то имя подгружаемого модуля может стать известно только в рантайме.

Логично, что в этом случае файл не отправляется клиенту сразу при загрузке основного скрипта, а должен быть затребован только спустя какое-то время.

Вот, собственно, и интересует, **как**. Там внутри что-то типа `fetch`?

И еще, это получается, все файлы, которые динамически импортируются, должны быть доступны извне? То есть если у меня, например, сервер настроен с фоллбэком на `index` для любого пути (clint-side routing то бишь), то нужно отдельно каждый файл, который может быть динамически подгружен, "открывать" для доступа по ссылке (чтобы скрипт его банально мог скачать)?

Или же каким-то образом все динамические импорты подпадают в бандл заранее и сразу отправляются клиенту? Но если так, то какой в этом смысл, если это не приводит к сокращению размера посылки (а это именно то, для чего динамические импорты создавались в первую очередь, насколько я понимаю)?

Comment: А вы точно не используете webpack или что-нибудь аналогичное?

Comment: @AlexeyTen вопрос не столько о каком-то конкретном бандлере, сколько о возможной реализации в целом. Понятно, что сейчас динамические импорты - stage 3 proposal, и бандлеры "подтасовывают" в клиент свои реализации ДИ, но ведь когда-нибудь они выйдут из стадии proposal и попадут в спецификацию окончательно, а следовательно и клиентская реализация должна будет какая-то появиться. Так что вопрос больше общий, чем о каком-то конкретном сборщике.

Comment: @AlexeyTen хотя если разговаривать не о заоблачном будущем, а о том, что имеется сейчас, то в целях упрощения ответа можно было рассмотреть поведение путь даже на том же webpack'е.

Comment: Да. В любом случае файл должен быть доступен для скачивания извне.

Comment: Если это браузерная имплементация (они уже есть), то файл на который будет ссылка, если вебпак, то файл который он сгенерит. Вообще в доках вебпака достаточно информации.

Comment: @AlexeyTen в доках вебпака есть инфа о динамическом импорте? А можно ссылочку? Там я не искал

Comment: Для статики лучше выделить отдельный путь (обычно assets или несколько типа js, css, img) и запросы в эти папки никогда не роутить в index, т.е. либо файл либо 404.

Comment: эээ, а погуглить по банальному webpack dynamic import? https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: @AlexeyTen а, ну это я читал. Я думал там что-то конкретно о их реализации `import()`, а там про code-splitting в общем. Ну в целом кое-что прояснил в любом случае, благодарю. Меня больше всего именно момент с роутингом интересовал, теперь вроде понятно. Спасибо